# Question about directional derivative at a point

Tags: calculus

A silly question. For example, let $f(x, y)=xy$, then it's a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and it is differentiable everywhere, so at a point $(a_1, a_2)$, the directional derivative at $a$ along directional $(v_1, v_2)$ is [$D_xf$ $  D_yf$]$(v_1, v_2)$ = $[a_2$ $ a_1](a_1, a_2)$.

Then let $v_1= (1, 2)$,  $v_2 = (2, 4)$, then is it right that $v_1, v_2$ point in the same direction? If it is, the two vectors point in the same direction, why, at any fixed point a, are the directional derivatives of $f$ along the two vectors different?

Answer (score 1):

Since $v_2 = 2v_1$ which means they have the "same direction" and call it $u = \dfrac{v_1}{||v_1||}$. This means the directional derivatives are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

You have to normalize your vectors to get unit vectors then find directional derivative by the dot product of the gradient vector and the unit vector.

If your vectors point at the same direction you have the same unit vectors so you have the same directional derivative.

Answer (score 0):

To take the directional derivative along the direction of a given vector, we take the linear combination of the partials using the components of the *unit vector* in the direction in question as scaling factors.

Thus in a fixed direction, the derivative is always uniquely defined.